# Inserting data into a table with foreign key

Tags: node.js, react-native

I want to get users_id that is a foreign key in post table ...
and insert in post table!!!
How can insert user_id from login  into post ????

I want to get users_id from this function...

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    if (!username || !password) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "there is noo login"
      });
    }
    const query = SQL`SELECT username ,password,users_id FROM Users WHERE username = ${username} AND password = ${password}`;
    const student = await db.all(query);
    if (student.length === 0) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Please check you login"
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        user: student,

      });
    }
  });
```

And insert it in this table by this function...

```
app.post("/post", async (req, res, next) => {
    const { title, text } = req.body;

    if (!title || !text ) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Complete your Post "
      });
    }

    try  {
        const query = `INSERT INTO Post (title,text,users_id) VALUES 
        ('${title}','${text}',????????) `;
        console.log(second_query);
        const query2 = await db.run(query );
        if (query2.length === 0) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Please check your post"
          });
        }

        res.json({
          success: true,
          dat: query2.stmt.lastID,

        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("===err===>", err);
    }

    next();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using bare-bone nodejs, with no libraries or framework to handle currently logged-in user session. I suggest you look into tutorials to properly implement and handle managing user sessions. Its a very bad idea to write your own when you have an easy to use and popular libraries. With a framework you would have a global object representing the currently logged in user. So your code will look something like this: `INSERT INTO Post (title,text,users_id) VALUES ('${title}','${text}',globalUserObject.id)`